# how to use @providesModule with Jest and react-native

Tags: javascript, module, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest for unit testing react-native and I'm using the @providesModule successfully in the app, but Jest is failing to load the modules using this format
"import Component from "Component"

jest: version 13.2.3
react-native: 0.29.0

The error is:

```
FAIL  js/components/home/__tests__/TestHome.js (0s)
 Runtime Error
  - Error: Cannot find module 'Time' from 'TimelineItem.js'
        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:197:17)
```

There is a small reference to 'providesModule and jest' on a blog post here
https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/06/22/jest-13.html

but it's not clear exactly what needs to be done.

If someone has @providesModule working with Jest and react-native, could you please help by indicating exactly what needs to be done?

Comment: can you show us your code snippet

Comment: Off-topic, but do you have a reference to getting `@providesModule` working in app?

Comment: to get @providesModule working in the App I make sure to put the annotate at the very top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

with Jest 14.0 you can use [Snapshot Test](http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/07/27/jest-14.html)

You have to use React's `react-test-renderer` to render your component first